# Scheduled posting not working

Tags: posts, hosting, wp-cron

I have Wordpress 3.5.1 and I use Bluehost hosting service. When I schedule posts after that time passed, WP posts dashboard shows "Missed schedule" message under the date. Then I checked my `wp-config.php` has `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);` there's no such a  define line. Then I added `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', false);` under the database lines. After that I added following code to my `.htaccess` file.

```
<Files "wp-cron.php">
Allow from All
Satisfy Any
</Files>
```

But still this issue not fixed. What is the reason? Is it my hosting company issue or my WP issue? How do i fix it?

Comment: Enable [debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and set it to write to a log file. Post related debugging data.

Comment: I haven't noticed a problem on Bluehost in the past, but could be good to bring it up with them. I would be curious to know where that DISABLE_WP_CRON line came from.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that line in wp-config.php as wp-cron is enabled by default.

If you install the [Cron View](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cron-view/) plugin you are able to see when the different jobs are scheduled. You can then trigger wp-cron manually by going to this URL with your browser:

```
http://your-domain.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron
```

If after this the actions you expected where successfully performed. You really have a problem with your hosting provider. Maybe he has cURL/fsockopen disabled or the DNS is not properly configured so he can't resolve an IP for your domain. In that case you would need to contact tech-support.

Comment: S1Lv3r, I have installed "Cron View" plug-in, it shows some of my plug-in schedule tasks. If i go to this URL http://your-domain.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron It shows website offline mode (I use CloudFlare).

Comment: Updated! After I have disabled W3 Total Cache no issue. Looks like it's W3 Total cache issue. Thanks all of you guys your support. :D

Comment: Chathu, did you manage to fix the problem with W3 Total Cache or you just stopped using it? I got the same issue with the plugin, but I don't want to deactivate it as I need it...

Comment: If you're using Page Caching, make sure wp-cron.php is one of the pages that is never cached in the cache settings.